# aggregate function - NA is still outputted as na.action is set to omit

Tags: r

I'm quite new to R. So I'm a little confused right now.

I'm using the aggregate function on a list, now it generates all values correctly except for those columns containing NA's. I'm computing the mean.

The data in question is below

```
  AreaSize constructionYear
6        30             1980
7        30               NA
13       30             1969
```

Now the aggregate table gives this.

```
  SegGroup listPrice   rent livingArea constructionYear soldPrice
1       20   2383750 1353.0   25.87500           1927.5   2813750
2       30   2161667 1856.0   36.50000               NA   2428333
3       40   3548333 2381.0   44.16667               NA   3858333
4       50   2261667 3601.0   56.66667               NA   2616667
5       60   2395000 3320.0   63.00000           1954.0   2700000
6       70   3837500 3274.0   72.50000           1946.5   3942500
7       80   3335000 4759.5   82.75000           1986.0   3400000
8       90   2720000 4017.5   92.50000           1950.0   3475000
```

Even though the na.action = na.omit within the aggregate function (set by default). What is wrong?

Code

```
listPrice  <- aggregate(lOriginal[-length(lOriginal)], list(lOriginal$AreaSize), FUN = mean)
```

Comment: What is the code you've used?

Comment: I have added the aggregate line of code I'm using.

Comment: have you tried `aggreagte(....,FUN=mean, na.rm=T)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the help on `aggregate`, `na.action = na.omit` is the default in the method for formula objects, but not in the method for data frames. Which method  is used is determined by the class of the first argument in your function call.

I don't have your data, so I show you what this means using the data set `mtcars`, which is included in R, with a modification (which is needed, because `mtcars` contains no `NA`):

```
mtcars[5, "disp"] <- NA
```

Now, I aggregate the columns `disp` and `mpg` by `cyl`. First, I use the data frame method:

```
aggregate(mtcars[, c("mpg", "disp")], list(cyl = mtcars$cyl), mean)
##   cyl      mpg     disp
## 1   4 26.66364 105.1364
## 2   6 19.74286 183.3143
## 3   8 15.10000       NA
```

Clearly, the `NA` values are not omitted. However, `mean()` comes with an argument `na.rm`, which I can set to `TRUE` as follows:

```
aggregate(mtcars[, c("mpg","disp")], list(cyl = mtcars$cyl), mean, na.rm = TRUE)
##   cyl      mpg     disp
## 1   4 26.66364 105.1364
## 2   6 19.74286 183.3143
## 3   8 15.10000 352.5692
```

(The reason that this works can also be found in the documentation of `aggregate()`. The function has an argument `...` (as many R functions do), which will match all the expressions that you pass to the function that do not match one of its arguments. These expressions are than passed on to the function that you use for aggregation. Since `aggregate()` has no argument called `na.rm`, this argument will sent on to `mean()`.)

Now back to what caused your confusion: you can also use aggregate by giving a formula as the first argument (which I find more readable and thus preferable). The call then reads as follows:

```
aggregate(cbind(mpg, disp) ~ cyl, data = mtcars, mean)
##   cyl      mpg     disp
## 1   4 26.66364 105.1364
## 2   6 19.74286 183.3143
## 3   8 14.82308 352.5692
```

As you can see, in this form the `NA` values are indeed omitted by default.